# (Unity) 2D game collision script with Lava - 3 Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm creating a code for a "Lava" block in Unity where the once the player touches it, the player respawns. But I receive 3 errors which I don't understand where's the problem.
Errors:

- Assets\KillScript.cs(14,45): error CS1002: ; expected
- Assets\KillScript.cs(13,31): error CS1513: } expected
- Assets\KillScript.cs(13,31): error CS1002: ; expected
  Here is the code (script attached to player sprite);

  ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;

   public class KillScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
       {
           if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Lava")
           {
               Destroy(gameObject);
           }
           if (gameObject)Destroy) {
               current.transformation.position new vector3(-0.37, -0.13, 0);
           }
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: What are the 3 errors? Copy/paste them into the question please. I see two things that are obviously wrong. Read the errors and code carefully. The errors tell you a line and column so you know where to focus.

Comment: The posted code looks strange. You are casting in an if statement, you are trying to assign without equals etc etc.

Comment: There are unmatched parentheses in the code.

Comment: Your **if(gameObject)Destroy)**  code is wrong,fix it. What is current variable , is it defined in kill script? Can you share your all killscript code ?

Answer (score 1):

For your if statement, I would suggest using a bool to check whether or not your player is dead. Also Line 14 has no equals sign between Vector3 and  current.transformation.position, as well as Vector3 not being capitalized.
Another problem is the decimals not have an f after them.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KillScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isDead;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Lava")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            isDead = true;
        }
        if (isDead = true)
        {
            current.transformation.position = new Vector3(-0.37f, -0.13f, 0);
            isDead = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'm not sure what current.transformation.position is. You could use a prefab to create a clone, then set that position to the Vector3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

1. If I counted correctly... what is current.transformation?? That may be part of it. But you should point out in the question what line it says the errors are on, so we don't have to try to count it all. Oh, also let's just go through this line of code. current.transformation.. what is that? do you mean transform? transform.position? then you actually need to use an equals sign, not just ...formation new vector3(...   and finally, Vector3 should be capitalized.
2. Again, what is (gameObject)Destroy)??? There is *no way* that code is going to compile. There is an extra bracket there. What exactly were you trying to do?
3. Again, maybe don't always take errors at face value, it may just be that it doesn't understand what you were trying to do. But, I will try and offer suggestions  as to what code would work, I think.

First off, it looks like (gameObject)Destroy is checking if the GameObject is destroyed. See, the problem with that is kind of that if the GameObject *is* destroyed, then this script is also destroyed...?
And I'm pretty sure current.transformation.position was meant to be transform.position? And you also need the equals, and Vector3 should be capitalized.